# How to change html structure ,using media queries?

Tags: html, web, frontend, mobile-website, web-frontend

We can change css using media queries,what I basically want to know is can we change html structure when screen width and height change ,is this possible,then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the structure of the HTML , but you could change the order , direction , etc of the elements on the screen with css so you could with media queries , Flexbox and Grid are very useful things for that